# Select não retornar repetidos com base em uma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Me deparei com uma situação onde tenho um cadastro de clientes que podem ter mais de um endereço na tabela tbEndereco relacionada e um endereço pode pertencer a mais de um cliente. Mas ao consultar os clientes preciso retornar apenas 1 desses endereços, sendo aquele que apareccer primeiro (nao ha criterio). Esquema simplificado a seguir:

- tbCliente : idCliente, Nome
- tbCliEnd: idCliente, idEndereco
- tbEndereco: idEndereco, endereco
- tbPedido: idPedido, idCliente, descricao

Estou tentando:

```
SELECT c.idCliente, c.Nome, e.endereco, p.descricao
FROM tbPedido p
INNER JOIN tbCliente c 
ON p.idCliente = c.IdCliente
INNER JOIN tbCliEnd ce
ON c.idCliente = ce.idCliente
INNER JOIN tbEndereco e
ON e.idEndereco = ce.idEndereco
```

Porem os clientes que possuem mais de um endereço acabam aparecendo "repetidos". Eles vem contendo em cada linha um endereço diferente, mas sob o mesmo nome e id de cliente.
Como posso fazer para que apenas um dos endereços seja retornado?

Comment: coloca o seu exemplo em http://sqlfiddle.com/ fica mais fácil para te ajudar

Comment: AlamO, em `tbPedido` não tem um campo referente a `idEndereco` em `tbEndereco`? Por que como você saberá qual endereço entregar se há mais de 1 cadastrado no cliente? Ao meu ver é uma falha. Se não há nenhuma referência, então como irá buscar apenas 1 endereço se não sabe qual deve buscar!? Quando ao filtrar o endereço ao adicionar o pedido, aí sim você usa a tabela `tbCliEnd` para fazer o filtro de quais endereços são permitidos para tal cliente.

Comment: @RBZ Infelizmente não há referência ao endereço na tabPedido. Este é um banco antigo, que atende outros sistemas e não posso modifica-lo. De qualquer maneira esta consulta não é para alimentar entregas, apenas um relatório. Preciso apenas que apareça um dos endereços, indiferente de qual seja.

Comment: usar o Distinct poderia ajudar aqui?

Comment: @AlamO O que você poderia fazer no caso, é adicionar um campo, como por exemplo: `principal`, e permitir que sempre só terá 1 endereço principal do cliente. Isso resolveria muita coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o utilizador [@ThiagoMagalhães](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/120087/thiago-magalh%C3%A3es) postou não irá funcionar porque o *alias* `ce` não é reconhecido dentro do `INNER JOIN`.

Visto que a ordenação não interessa, a solução será obter o endereço a partir de um `MAX`:

```
SELECT      c.idCliente
        ,   c.Nome
        ,   MAX(e.endereco) AS endereco
        ,   p.descricao
FROM        tbPedido    p
INNER JOIN  tbCliente   c   ON p.idCliente  = c.IdCliente
INNER JOIN  tbCliEnd    ce  ON c.idCliente  = ce.idCliente
INNER JOIN  tbEndereco  e   ON e.idEndereco = ce.idEndereco
GROUP BY    c.idCliente
        ,   c.Nome
        ,   p.descricao
```